# RSS feed in flex mobile project

Tags: apache-flex, flash-builder, flex-mobile

I am working on accessing RSS feed  using Flex mobile project. But i dont get image in that RSS feed,how to get image from RSS feed in Flex mobile project and how to convert an image into byte stream in Flex mobile project

Answer (score 0):

> But i dont get image in that RSS feed

RSS is xml. You need to looking for `image` elements, get url and load images separately 
http://www.w3schools.com/rss/rss_tag_image.asp

> how to convert an image into byte stream

In order to load image as ByteArray you need to use URLLoader for image loading:

```
var loader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
loader.dataFormat = URLLoaderDataFormat.BINARY;
loader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, loader_completeHandler);

function loader_completeHandler(event:Event):void
{
    //here you can get loaded image as ByteArray
    var imageData:ByteArray = loader.data;
}
```

If after this you need to show image in display list then:

```
var loader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
loader.dataFormat = URLLoaderDataFormat.BINARY;
loader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, loader_completeHandler);

var imageBytesLoader:Loader = new Loader();
imageBytesLoader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, imageBytesLoader_completeHandler);

function loader_completeHandler(event:Event):void
{
    //here you can get loaded image as ByteArray
    var imageData:ByteArray = loader.data;

    imageBytesLoader.loadBytes(imageData);
}

function imageBytesLoader_completeHandler(event:Event):void
{
    //here you can get loaded image as Bitmap
    var bitmap:Bitmap = Bitmap(imageBytesLoader.content);
}
```